# Jquery ajaxStart doesnt get triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
        alert("start");
        $(this).show();
    });
```

in my mark-up

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><img id="loading" src="../images/common/loading.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

Here is the full ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",       

        url: "http://localhost/WebServices/Service.asmx/GetResults",

        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {

            var results = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            PopulateTree(results);
        },

        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(msg.Message);


        }
    });

$("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
        alert("start");
        $(this).show();
    });

    $("#loading").ajaxStop(function() {
        alert("stop");
        $(this).hide();
        $("#st-tree-container").show();

    });
```

never fires alert "start" even though the gif is shown to rotate. AjaxStop gets triggered as expected.
Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by "even though the gif is shown to rotate?"  I don't see any markup or JS with a gif in your question.  Are you invoking your ajax call with the same instance of jQuery with which your ajaxStart() handler is registered?

Comment: scroll right in my mark-up, you will see the gif there.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's not getting triggered because your handler for [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) isn't registered until **after** the ajax request is already going (past when it would have been called).  The [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) is registered after as well, but **before** the request finishes, so when it comes back it is hooked up to run.

To fix this, move this **before** your first [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#st-tree-container").show();
});
```

**UPDATE: Starting jQuery 1.9, AJAX events should be attached to document only.**
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
  $("#st-tree-container").show();
});
```

Comment: it will solve the problem but when we do multiple ajax call then this solution is a problem because then only same loading image probably in the wrong place will be shown . Suppose multiple call happend then how to target loading image for that particular call which initiated the call

Answer (score 4):

**Starting jQuery 1.9, AJAX events should be attached to document only.**

Refer migration guide. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document

As of jQuery 1.9, the global AJAX events (ajaxStart, ajaxStop, ajaxSend, ajaxComplete, ajaxError, and ajaxSuccess) are only triggered on the document element. Change the program to listen for the AJAX events on the document. For example, if the code currently looks like this:

```
$("#status").ajaxStart(function() { 
   $(this).text("Ajax started"); 
});
```

Change it to this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#status").text("Ajax started");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue, but generally I use `debug.info('your message')` in combination with the Firebug console instead of `alert()`, as alert interrupts your script processing until you dismiss it whereas debug.info is fairly unobtrusive.

You can download the implementation of [debug.info](http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/) here.

Comment: i have never heard of debug.info(), will it for work for IE? I am working with IE

Comment: I added a link to the library in the answer.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like it will work in IE, but I would highly recommend Firefox + Firebug for debugging.