# Display 'loading' image when AJAX call is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "addtobasket.php",
                   data: "sid=<?= $sid ?>&itemid=" + itemid + "&boxsize=" + boxsize + "&ext=" + extraval,
                   success: function(msg){
                     $.post("preorderbasket.php", { sid: "<?= $sid ?>", type: "pre" },
                     function(data){
                        $('.preorder').empty();
                         $('.preorder').append(data); 
                     }); 
                   }
                 });
```

I want to display an image when the ajax call is in progress. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#loading')
            .hide()
            .ajaxStart(function() {
                $(this).show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
    });
</script>

<div id="loading">
        Loading....
</div>
```

This will show the loading image each time you are doing an ajax request, I have implented this div at the top of my pages, so it does not obstruct with the page, but you can always see when an ajax call is going on.

Comment: Note this will show the loading div when *any* ajax requests are in progress.

Answer (score 7):

Something along these lines (`showLoadingImage` and `hideLoadingImage` are up to you):

```
// show the loading image before calling ajax.
showLoadingImage();

$.ajax({
    // url, type, etc. go here
    success: function() {
        // handle success. this only fires if the call was successful.
    },
    error: function() {
        // handle error. this only fires if the call was unsuccessful.
    },
    complete: function() {
        // no matter the result, complete will fire, so it's a good place
        // to do the non-conditional stuff, like hiding a loading image.

        hideLoadingImage();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's also a beforeSend parameter in the ajax object

Answer (score 1):

You can display the image just before this call to $.ajax() and then hide/remove the image in the post handler function (just before your .empty()/.append(data) calls.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I have tested it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#but_search").click(function(){
var search = $('#search').val();

$.ajax({
 url: 'fetch_deta.php',
type: 'post',
data: {search:search},
beforeSend: function(){
 // Show image container
$("#loader").show();
},
success: function(response){
 $('.response').empty();
$('.response').append(response);
},
complete:function(data){
// Hide image container
$("#loader").hide();
}
});

});
});
</script>

<input type='text' id='search'>
<input type='button' id='but_search' value='Search'><br/>

<!-- Image loader -->
<div id='loader' style='display: none;'>
  <img src='reload.gif' width='32px' height='32px'>
</div>
<!-- Image loader -->

<div class='response'></div>
```