# How to add a loading screen while waiting for search result to show up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a home page that contains a texfield that reads the user input, sends the value of whatever is typed in and sends it to another page where the search will happen and display the search results.

```
 <div>
     <form action="****.jsp" method="get" id="search-id">
          <input type ="text" name = "search" id="search" size="70"/><br>
          <br />
          <input type="Submit" value="Search"  class="button rounded"> 
     </form>
     <br />
     <br />
     <br />
</div>
```

But the thing is that it takes some time before the actual second page shows up, therefore I wanted to make a little loading gif to appear while waiting for that page to actually load up. I have a gif file ready to use, but I can't figure out how to implement it into the website so that it would show up after I click on the search button.

I'm very new to `HTML/JS` and I been searching for a possible way for days. Is this possible at all?

Comment: It seems like you should check out AJAX, which is a way to send http-requests without reloading an entire page. That could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a submit event handler to your form, that makes the animated gif appear and doesn't prevent the form submission. Example with JQuery:

```
$('#search-id').submit(function() {
    $('#animated-gif').show();
});
```

assuming you have the animated gif hidden somewhere in the page:

```
<img src="..." style="display: none;" id="animated-gif"/>
```

Comment: Hey there I tried what you wrote, but the gif still shows up on the first page without me clicking on the search button. even if I made a class to tell it to not display.

Comment: Sorry. It's `style="display: none;"` and not `class="display: none;"`. (or you could create a CSS class which contains this style, of course.

Comment: yeah I did that, I thought that was what you meant :) But now that it's not displaying, even when I click submit, it wont show it for some reason. is there I special spot I have to put this javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to `HTML`, you will need to search more about `ajax and jquery`. That will ideally answer your question. Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082323/display-loading-image-when-ajax-call-is-in-progress) similar question as well. Hope this will help you.