# How to improve Ajax call using jquery and deferreds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making four or more ajax rest calls in `$(document).ready(function(){}`. 
As a hack, I added `.done()` to largest call. It is "working." I want to improve and add a spinning gif for part of page, not on entire body.  I tried method for entire body, the spinner launches on my page transitions. I would like to avoid that.

```
$.getJSON("//urls", function( data ) { data122 = data });
$.getJSON("//urls", function( data ) { data212 = data});
$.getJSON("//urls", function( data ) { data21 = data});
$.getJSON("//urls", function( data ) { data12 = data});


$.getJSON("//urls", function( data ) { survey = data})
    .done(function() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use deferred:

```
$(function() { // on document ready
    $("#spinner").show(); // show the spinner

    var a = $.getJSON(...);
    var b = $.getJSON(...);
    // more calls...

    $.when(a,b).always(function() {
        $("#spinner").hide();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: How would I add a spinner to this..Can use with $.ajaxSetup({})

Comment: Updated to show clarity of usage. I would recommend against using global ajax handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#loading')
            .hide()
            .ajaxStart(function() {
                $(this).show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
    });
</script>

<div id="loading">
        Loading....
</div>
```

I found this one here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082403/2630817