# How to show loading image while content loads using jquery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show loading image while jquery loads my content into the page.
Currently I use this to load my content:

```
$.post('page.php', {para1: value1}, function(data){
    // post content here
});
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to show image buffering while loading.

Comment: Show the image before you call `$.post`, and hide it in the callback function.

Comment: Use `.show()` and `.hide()` to do this. Why isn't that obvious?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display 'loading' image when AJAX call is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082323/display-loading-image-when-ajax-call-is-in-progress)

Answer (score 0):

Show the loader image before calling ajax and hideit on getting the response.

```
$('img.loader').show();
$.post('page.php', {para1: value1}, function(data){
    $('img.loader').hide();
    // post content here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="loader" src="/loader.png" style="display:none"/>
```

---

```
("button").click(function(){
    $('.loader').fadeIn();
    $.post('page.php', {para1: value1}, function(data, status){
        $('.loader').fadeOut();
    });
});
```