# Show page with animation while doing async method and then redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.0

```
public IActionResult Processing()
{
    DoWork();
    return View(); // returning Processing.cshtml
    // which contains page with animation
}

private async void DoWork()
{
    await DoSomething();
    // and here I want to redirect
    // from page with animation to
    // to an action
}
```

How to redirect to action from async method? Animation page must shows all the time while `await DoSomething()` works with data.

Comment: You need to be careful with your approach. Not awaiting a `Task` and doing `async void` it's just asking for problems. I recommend you to read a little about async programming.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't.

Since you're not awaiting on the `Task` returned by the `DoWork` method, the HTTP transaction will have ended before `DoWork` finishes executing.

Switch to a client-side solution in JavaScript:

1. Start running the animation
2. Call the long-running operation with an XHR
3. Stop the animation when the HXR completes

See this thread for an exemple: [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed).