# Onclick Loader is not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi All I have used loader icon in my project it's working fine but few places it's taking 1-2 second time to appear when clicks on button

I have found lot of answers related to this

[show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

but still my problem persist

Loading Icon is not working on click & Ajax call please check below code for reference.

```
    $("#delyesRemoveAccountCode").click(function () {
 //Loader is appearing after 2 second if i am using setTimeout function,  
    setTimeout(function () {
       overlayFull("show");
    }, 200);

   //this is executing loader throughout whole application but here it's not working
    overlayFull("show");

    var objDelete = {
        "CostItemId": null,
        "ComparableAccountCodeId": accountCodeId,
        "CBSCode": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Cost": null,
        "ManHours": null,
        "Quantity": null,
        "UnitOfMeasureValue": null,
        "UnitRate": null,
        "ModifiedDate": null,
        "AccountCodes": []
    };
    $("#costDetailgrid tr td input").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).val().match(code) && $(this).val().trim().indexOf(code) == 0) {
            var accountCodesArray = {
                "AccountCodeId": 0,
                "AccountLevel": 0,
                "Code": "0",
                "DisciplineId": 0,
                "ParentAccountCodeId": 0,
                "AccountId": 2,
            };
            accountCodesArray.Code = $(this).val().trim();
            accountCodesArray.AccountCodeId = $(this).data('accountcodeid');
            objDelete.AccountCodes.push(accountCodesArray);
        }
    });
//    overlayFull("show");
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: remoteServername + 'odata/CostItemSaveAs(' + comparableID + ')',
        data: objDelete,
      //  beforeSend: function () {
       //     overlayFull("show");
      //  },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            overlayFull("hide");
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            if (comparableID != null) {
                $("#costDetailgrid tr.costItemEditRow,#costDetailgrid tr.costItemAddRow").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                costdetailTreeListLoad();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    overlayFull("hide");
                }, 1000);
                ComTreeList.ResetTreeList('mngRecordCostDetailsTreeList', 'mngRecordCostDetailsTreeListSelectedTab');
            }
            else {
                $(".norecordSecrion").show();
                $("#costDetailgrid").hide();
            }
        },
        type: 'PATCH'
    })
});
```

Comment: `async: false` <-- WHY? That locks up the browser and does not allow the page to update. Make the call asynchronous.

Comment: add loader on before: function @ ajax and disable loader on complete: function or done.

Comment: The link you pasted is outdated. See duplicate

Comment: @epascarello what i need to change Make the call asynchronous?

Comment: @GrzegorzMiśkiewicz I have tried onbefore also but nothing is happening

Comment: Well you set the async flag to false....

Comment: As @epascarello says - async is a problem - take a look: https://jsbin.com/weqerumaya/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @GrzegorzMiśkiewicz ok let me try..

Comment: @epascarello  async: true is working fine .  thank you for the idea