# Ajax Loader on button click - error with code

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've followed other advice regarding showing an Ajax Loading Gif on button click to submit a form, however I can't seem to get the code working.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="job_manager_form" value="<?php echo $form; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $job_id ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" />

                    <?php if($job_id){ ?>
                    <img src="https://www.salusa.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ajax-loader.gif" id="img" style="display:none"/ >
                    <input type="submit" id="submitjob" name="submit_job" class="button" value="Update my service profile" />


                    <?php } else { ?>
                     <img src="https://www.salusa.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ajax-loader.gif" id="img" style="display:none"/ >
                    <input type="submit" id="submitjob" name="submit_job" class="button" value="Submit profile for admin approval" />
                    <?php } ?>

    </p>

<script>
                    $('#submitjob').click(function(){
                    $('#img').show();
                    $.ajax({
                    ....
                    success:function(result){
                    $('#img').hide();  //<--- hide again
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: There should be an error to the php file that you POST your form via ajax. What you could do is after ajax success function to console log the result and check for any errors from the response

Comment: Do you prevent default behaviour of form's submit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Answer (score 0):

The Code won't work if your Ajax request is having the errors or if you don't include necessary scripts for jquery. Based on what you did above, I'm having the working example, have it for your reference:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ajax Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="hidden" name="job_manager_form" value="<?php echo $form; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $job_id ); ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="step" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" />


  <!-- Here comes your if condition -->
  <img src="https://www.salusa.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ajax-loader.gif" id="img" style="display:none" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitjob" name="submit_job" class="button" value="Update my service profile" />

  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

<script>
  $('#submitjob').click(function() {
    $('#img').show();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
      type: 'GET',

      error: function() {
        $('#content').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        $('#content').html("data Received" + result);
        $('#img').hide(); //<--- hide again
      },
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```