# How to display loading gif before inserting the data in this scenario?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#modal-dialog').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

the 'data' in the success function is used to alert "Data inserted". I need to load the gif before this "Data inserted" alert.

Comment: This can be useful to show loading before ajax call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed

Comment: @TechnoCrat my insert form is in the bootstrap modal...

Comment: show loading gif before ajax call and hide gif into "complete" method, ajax provides a complete method and you can use it for.

Comment: @RajKumar has answered it. you can use before callback method for it.

Answer (score 0):

first you should include on jquery file 
And then create one js file given below name

**jquery-loader.js**

```
(function($) {
     $.loader_ext = {

         defaults: {
             autoCheck: 32,
             css: {},
             size: 16,
             bgColor: '#000',
             bgOpacity: 0.6,
             fontColor: false,
             position: [0, 0, 0, 0],
             title: '',
             isOnly: true,
             imgUrl: 'img/loading.gif',
             onShow: function() {},
             onClose: function() {}
         },

         template: function(tmpl, data) {
             $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                 tmpl = tmpl.replace('${' + k + '}', v);
             });
             return $(tmpl);
         },

         init: function(scope, options) {
             this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
             this.scope = scope;

             if (this.scope.is(':hidden')) {
                 return;
             }
             this.checkScope();
             this.check_position();
             this.check_unique();
             this.create();
             this.set_css();
             this.set_define();
             this.show();

             return this.loading;
         },

         checkScope: function() {
             if (!this.options.autoCheck) {
                 return;
             }
             if (this.scope.is('body') || this.scope.is('div') || this.scope.is('form')) {
                 this.options.size = this.options.autoCheck;
             }
             if (this.scope.is('input') || this.scope.is('button')) {
                 this.options.title = '';
             }
         },

         check_position: function() {
             var pos = this.options.position;
             for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                 if (pos[i] === undefined) {
                     pos[i] = 0;
                 }
             }
             this.options.position = pos;
         },

         check_unique: function() {
             if (this.options.isOnly && this.loading !== undefined) {
                 this.close();
             }
         },

         create: function() {
             var ops = this.options;
             ops.imgUrl = ops.imgUrl.replace('[size]', ops.size + 'x' + ops.size);
             this.loading = this.template($.loader.tmpl, {
                 Class: 'x' + ops.size,
                 Src: ops.imgUrl,
                 Title: ops.title
             }).hide();
             this.loading.appendTo($('body'));
         },

         set_css: function() {
             var scope = this.scope,
                 ops = this.options,
                 loading = this.loading,
                 height = scope.outerHeight(),
                 width = scope.outerWidth(),
                 top = scope.offset().top,
                 left = scope.offset().left;

             loading.css('top', top);

             if (scope.is('body')) {
                 height = $(window).height();
                 width = $(window).width();
                 loading.css('position', 'fixed');

                 this.for_ie6();
             }

             loading.css({
                 'height': height + ops.position[2],
                 'width': width + ops.position[3],
                 'left': left,
                 'border-radius': scope.css('border-radius')
             }).css(ops.css);

             var loader = loading.children();
             loader.css({
                 'margin-top': (height - ops.size) / 2 + ops.position[0],
                 'margin-left': (width - ops.size) / 2 + ops.position[1] - loader.find('span').outerWidth() / 2
             });
         },

         set_define: function() {
             var ops = this.options,
                 loading = this.loading;
             if (!ops.bgColor) {
                 loading.css('background', 'none');
             } else {
                 loading.css({
                     'background-color': ops.bgColor,
                     'opacity': ops.bgOpacity,
                     'filter': 'alpha(opacity=' + ops.bgOpacity * 100 + ')'
                 });
             }

             ops.fontColor && loading.find('span').css('color', ops.fontColor);

             var self = this;
             $(window).resize(function() {
                 self.loading && self.set_css();
             })
         },

         for_ie6: function() {
             var loading = this.loading;
             if ($.browser && $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
                 loading.css({
                     'position': 'absolute',
                     'top': $(window).scrollTop()
                 });

                 $(window).scroll(function() {
                     loading.css("top", $(window).scrollTop());
                 })
             }
         },

         show: function() {
             var ops = this.options;
             this.loading.show(1, function() {
                 var loader = $(this).children();
                 var left = loader.css('margin-left').replace('px', '');
                 loader.css('margin-left', left - loader.find('span').outerWidth() / 2);
                 ops.onShow(this.loading);
             });
         },

         close: function(all) {
             if (all) {
                 var className = $($.loader.tmpl).attr('class');
                 $('.' + className).remove();
             } else {
                 if (this.loading != undefined) {
                     this.loading.remove();
                     this.loading = undefined;
                 }
             }
             this.options != undefined && this.options.onClose();
         }
     };
     $.loader = {
         tmpl: '<div class="loading_wrp"><div class="loading ${Class}"><img src="${Src}" /><span>${Title}</span></div></div>',

         open: function(arg) {
             return $('body').loader(arg);
         },
         close: function(all) {
             $.loader_ext.close(all);
         }
     };

     $.fn.loader = function(arg) {
         if (!$(this).size()) {
             return;
         }
         if ($.type(arg) === "string") {
             arg = {
                 title: arg
             }
         }
         var dom = $(this);
         if (dom.size() > 1) {
             dom = dom.parent();
         }
         return $.loader_ext.init(dom, arg);
     };

 })(jQuery);
```

Then you can add one gif named as **loading.gif**. Then you can include the newly created js file into your html like

Then change your code like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    $.loader.open();// opening the loader
     $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#modal-dialog').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
                 $.loader.close();// closing the loader
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

This is working fine in my case please have a try on this.
This will help you.