# How do I load an html document after a certain few javascript instructions have executed?

Tags: javascript, html, api, document

I'm using an API to display some data on a page. So I create an XMLHttpRequest object, set the URL and send the request to get the data to display.
Now when I load the page it displays the placeholder text for a second before I get the actual data in there. I think there's a delay because I'm also converting the JSON into and object and then displaying.

So is there a way to tackle this. I figured that I probably can't reduce the delay caused from the API fetching. So can I just make my page not load till I get the data?

```
    request.onload = function() {
          var obj;
          obj = JSON.parse(request.response);
          var str = "stock";
          for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
          {
          //Here I set the innderHTML of a list with the API data.
          }
      };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Answer (score 0):

One of the normal behavior is setting a loader and set it's display status correctly. Have a look at the below question.
[Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate Global event handler: `onreadystatechange`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    // your code here


  }
};
xhr.send();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange