# How to operate a gif loading when using the window.location.href when downloading a document?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following click event handler, it exports and downloads a pdf, but I want to add a gif animation while the pdf is being generated. This is what I've tried so far:

```
 $("#export_pdf").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ajax_loader").css("display", "");
    var formato = "PDF";
    var url = "/Obras/Export?format=" + formato + "&nombreObra=" + 
    $('#nombre_obra').val();
    window.location.href = url;
    $("#ajax_loader").hide();
});
```

But it is not enough to show the image of the div by loading ajax_loader. **I am exporting a document in PDF**, using MVC C # and jquery, so I do not use ajax, so I use window.location.href.

I tried to do it, but it does not work for me. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with ajax loader but I've used jQuery spinner in the past:

html-

```
    <div id="loaderImportFile" class="loader">
    <div id="loadContent" class="loadContent">
        <p id="spinner" class="spinner">

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery-

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

         setSpinner("loaderImportFile");


         $('#importForm').submit(function () {

              $('#loaderImportFile').fadeIn();
         });

        function setSpinner(loaderId) {

            var opts = {
                lines: 12,
                length: 7,
                width: 4,
                radius: 10,
                color: '#000',
                speed: 1,
                trail: 60,
                shadow: false,
                hwaccel: false
          };
          var target = document.getElementById(loaderId);
          var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

         }

    });
```

Here's my bundle-

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/spin").Include(
            "~/Scripts/spin.js",
            "~/Scripts/spinner.js"));
```