# how to execute Javascript before ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are some issues related with this but none of them helped, this is the situation : I have a modal and on continue I want to show a loading gif which I already have and works fine.

The problem is my ajax code executes first so the loading gif shows for a milisec at the end and closes.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalChangeStatusGeneral" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="myLoader" class="loader"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="mdlStatusRobot">¡CARE!</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Doing smth?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeGeneralStatus()" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnContinuar">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function changeGeneralStatus() {
    $("#myLoader").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/changeStatus/',
        data:"",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hint: `async: false`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Comment: @Zak Why is this a duplicate?

Comment: That means its working fine, it loads until the data gets back and then you hit the refresh.. also why is this async: false?

Comment: Why would your image go away?  What does `refresh()` do?  Is there a form around this html that is getting submitted by the button click?

Comment: @james it refreshes the page so the modal and the loading are hidden

Comment: @Eric, Because if you read the responses to that question .. There are many ways to show the loader synchronously, and there are at least 2 answers in that OP that will help you out, even if the "question" isn't *labeled* "synchronous".

Comment: @Zak i have already tried those, but it doesnt work, it is weird cause if i add an alert on top it shows before and the loader after

Comment: @Zak plus, you can see i am using one of those solutions already..

Comment: Once the page starts to refresh the loader is going to disappear.

Comment: @Andreas hint: you didnt even read my code..

Comment: @James i know, i want that, but i want the loader to show while ajax is working

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the loader stick around longer than a millisecond?

Comment: @justDan yes, my ajax code goes to back end and does stuff, sometimes it lasts about 10 secs and i want the loader to keep spinning while java works.

Comment: I have... `async: false` blocks the browser from repainting the window = no loader. When the response arrives the blocking of the GUI stops and you see the loader for a short amount of time until `refresh() ` kicks in...

Comment: @EricStoppel Guessing you are not reading the comments. The reason why it does not render is because you are using a synchronous request. A synchronous request prevents the browser from updating. So you are causing the page to not update. There is really no reason for it to by synchronous. So if you set it to be asynchronous your loading stuff will appear (as long as the response take awhile to come back).

Comment: @epascarello geez, i was literally reading that they wanted me to put async: false, instead, it was the other way. I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here:

1. The ajax is not running first if it was you would see the spinner never go away because the show code would fire after the ajax. What you're seeing is proper, your spinner is shown but the response for the ajax call is so fast it goes away almost instantly.
2. If this is not what you want and you want to show the spinner for a little you could put your ajax call in a setTimeout() however in my opinion it's not needed.

Comment: in my backend it waits for about 5/10 secs, even on debug, it gets to the backend and it is not spinning....

Comment: get rid of this : async: false,

Comment: i did,  but my modal closes instant and the loading dismisses