# Display loading icon once while waiting for AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm populating a table with data that automatically updates every 4 seconds using AJAX. I want to display a loading message while waiting for the AJAX to load on the initial page load only.

At the moment I have managed to display the loading message but the message appears every time the data is updated via AJAX (Every 4 seconds) - I want the loading message to only display on the initial page load before the AJAX loads initially. All subsequent AJAX updates should not display the loading message as the table has already been populated with data.

`<div id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading..</div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#loading").show();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#load_onlineusers').load('/online_players.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 4000); 
</script>
```

```
<div id="load_onlineusers"> </div>
```

Above is the code that is causing the loading message to display every 4 seconds.

Comment: yes, your ajax call hits every 4 secs so loading icon show in that time. what do you want now?

Comment: You can put a boolean flag such as messageShown = false on pageload, then when message is shown the flag is set to true. Before showing the message again always check the flag value beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

Comment: Could you provide me with an example using the Boolean flag please? I have tried this approach but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `beforeSend` method to show loading message and control using a global variable:

```
var executed = false;
$.ajax({ url: "", 
    type: "", 
    data: "", 
    beforeSend: function() {
        if (!executed) {
            // Show loading
            executed = true;
        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        // Hide loading
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```