# Show loading image and text while aspx page is loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which when it is opened it starts running a method that takes 40 to 60 seconds to complete. I put a loading circle gif on the page but it doesn't appear until after the code is finished working. How can I make sure that the image is visible first?

**Update:**

I can successfully get a task to run my code after the gif appears. However, i need to either update the page or open another page after the task is complete. I have attempted the code below. When the `testLabel.visible = true` line is hit the label does not appear.

Any guidance to what i am doing wrong would be massively appreciated.

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            User currentUser = (User)Session["user"];
            Task task = new Task(() => StartProcessingAsync(currentUser));
            task.Start();
        }
    }

    public async void StartProcessingAsync(User currentUser)
    {
        await AsyncProcessing(currentUser);
        testLabel.Visible = true;
    }

    private async Task AsyncProcessing(User currentUser)
    {
        Company newCompany = CreateCompany();
        CreateUsers(newCompany, currentUser);          
    }
```

Comment: The method is running before page/view load. You need to have page load first, show img then trigger method simplest way. or add a timer to call method, or create a Task.

Comment: You can do it with AJAX too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed

Comment: Im trying to get the timer method to work. Will post outcome.

Comment: Have tried to use a Task and the image appears while the task runs. However, I need it to either update the UI or open a new page when the task is complete. I'm currenly try to get it make a hidden label to appear at the end of the task. The code hits that line but the UI does not update:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up building the long running method into a ASP.net RESTful web API which I call asynchronously when the page is loaded. I have eliminated any waiting required on the page and an email is sent to the logged in user when it has finished running which gives them the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {        
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $("#loading").fadeIn();
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 7, // The length of each line
                width: 4, // The line thickness
                radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('loading');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        }
    }); 
});


<div id="loading">
    <div id="loadingcontent">
        <p id="loadingspinner">
            Loading...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>     

<style>    
    #loading {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #loadingcontent {
        display: table;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #loadingspinner {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: larger;
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
</style>
```

Source: [Waiting spinner for long-running form submits in ASP MVC3 Razor using jQuery](http://blog.tkglaser.net/2012/02/waiting-spinner-for-long-running-form.html)