# Display loading gif when AJAX call is in progress

Tags: php, ajax

How can I show loading gif image while AJAX in progress? Not before, just when AJAX in progress. After that AJAX progress completed I need to show value in div id #statusT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formT button").click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault()
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "btn_tool") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '<?php echo APP_NAME;?>functions/app_form.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#statusT").html(data);
                    },
                    error:function (){}
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd show the gif initially(when pressing button) and then when the response is there hide the gif. Hard to believe you were not able to find examples/tuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an element for loadingImage. On page load keep the image hidden by default.
Show the gif image on button click and hide it again inside success() and error() both.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formT button").click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault()
            $("#loadingImage").show(); // <---
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "btn_tool") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '<?php echo APP_NAME;?>functions/app_form.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#loadingImage").hide(); // <---
                        $("#statusT").html(data);
                    },
                    error:function (){
                        $("#loadingImage").hide();  // <---
                        
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the gif with the JQuery's .hide() function.

```
$('#loading-image').show();
$.ajax({
      url: uri,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $('.info').append(html);
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      }
    });
```

There is a good example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed) Stack OverFlow question.

Comment: Do not just copy and paste a duplicate answer